# Docker build - returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: docker

I'm running on windows OS. I tried to build docker images on minikube using Git bash and on docker itself using docker terminal. I get error on line **RUN ["./gradlew", "clean", "build", "--debug"]**. On running the same command **./gradlew clean build --debug** on terminal it works.

Docker file: Docker-build

```
FROM openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["./gradlew", "clean", "build", "--debug"]
```

Terminal output:

```
Local User@PC MINGW64 /E/projects/authentication (master)
$ docker build -t my-image -f Dockerfile-build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   51.7MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine
 ---> 478bf389b75b
Step 2/4 : COPY . /app
 ---> 818b5bb8a22d
Removing intermediate container 02b237aa04c0
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> e238b49f5174
Removing intermediate container cd052cd7975a
Step 4/4 : RUN ./gradlew clean build --debug
 ---> Running in c47b21d9a0bc
': No such file or directory
The command './gradlew clean build --debug' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

**Note: gradlew is under my current directory /E/projects/authentication**

Comment: have you read this: "No such file or directory" ? maybe `RUN ["/app/gradlew", "clean", "build", "--debug"]`

Comment: Still same. Step 4/4 : RUN /app/gradlew clean build --debug
 ---> Running in e46107518dab
': No such file or directory
The command '/app/gradlew clean build --debug' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Comment out the `RUN`, build the image and run the command inside the container. `docker run -it my-image bash`, then run `./gradlew clean build --debug` manually.

Comment: which windows version ? do u use docker toolbox ?

Comment: remove tag minikube if it is not related

Comment: minikube tag removed. My windows version is win 8 and yes I use docker tool box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `gradlew text eol=lf` to .gitattributes worked for me as I was running from Git Bash on windows. This was due to cross platform end of line missing.

Comment: this answer provided the lead for me. I had earlier cloned a repo to my local and while executing, I was getting 'not found' error. Then I downloaded as zip and it worked! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
RUN ["./gradlew", "clean", "build", "--debug"]
```

to

```
RUN gradlew clean build --debug
```

For `RUN` command, there is no need to add `[,]`. that mostly for `CMD, ENTRYPOINT`

General solution to solve this is entering into the system to debug

for this case.

```
Removing intermediate container 02b237aa04c0
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> e238b49f5174  <== useful image !!
Removing intermediate container cd052cd7975a
```

Then you can run the image to check inside

```
docker run -it e238b49f5174 bash
# ls 
# gradlew clean build --debug
```

Mostly you will figure out what it is. Will be nice if you can put those codes (or partly) into github